# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in function call

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, call

I cannot figure out how to call a function in SQL Developer. I'm trying to call the function GET_SUIT but it says that I am using the wrong number or type of arguments in call to 'GET_SUIT':

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_SUIT 
(
  RND_NUM IN INTEGER, 
  Suit OUT VARCHAR2 
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN

if RND_NUM = 1 then -- Card is a Spade
  Suit := 'Spades';

elsif RND_NUM = 2 then  -- Card is a Heart
  Suit := 'Hearts';

elsif RND_NUM = 3 then -- Card is a Diamond
  Suit := 'Diamonds';

elsif RND_NUM = 4 then -- Card is an Club
  Suit := 'Clubs';

end if;

RETURN Suit;
END GET_SUIT;
```

I am using the following statement:

```
 SELECT dbms_random.value(1,4) into RND_NUM from dual;
 dbms_output.put_line('Random number 2 is : ' || RND_NUM);
 GET_SUIT(RND_NUM);
 dbms_output.put_line('Suit of card is : ' || Suit);
```

From everything I have read I need to pass one integer in to the function, is that correct? Any help would be appreciated I know this is basic level stuff but I have other functions that I would like to use and I can't even get this simple one to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error message for two reasons.

One, because your function takes two parameters but you  have only assigned one in the call.  You're missing a local variable to receive the OUT parameter.

Two, because a function returns a value.  Consequently the call must assign to a local variable; alternatively we can use functions in the projection of a SELECT statement.  This also means we don't use OUT parameters in the signature of a function (we could, the function still compiles, but it's bad practice).

So, write your function like this ...

```
create or replace FUNCTION GET_SUIT 
(
  RND_NUM IN INTEGER
) RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS 
  Suit  VARCHAR2(10); 
BEGIN

if RND_NUM = 1 then -- Card is a Spade
  Suit := 'Spades';

elsif RND_NUM = 2 then  -- Card is a Heart
  Suit := 'Hearts';

elsif RND_NUM = 3 then -- Card is a Diamond
  Suit := 'Diamonds';

elsif RND_NUM = 4 then -- Card is an Club
  Suit := 'Clubs';

end if;

RETURN Suit;
END GET_SUIT;
```

... and call it like this:

```
declare
    l_suit varchar2(10);
    rnd_num pls_integer;
begin
     SELECT dbms_random.value(1,4) into RND_NUM from dual;
     dbms_output.put_line('Random number 2 is : ' || RND_NUM);
     l_suit := GET_SUIT(RND_NUM);
     dbms_output.put_line('Suit of card is : ' || l_Suit);   
end;
/
```